# Describe the graph locus represented by this equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to know the shape of the region described by 
$$ Im(z^2) = 4 $$

so I did the following: 
$$ z=x + iy  $$

$$z^2 = x^2 + 2xiy -y^2  $$then 
$$Im(z^2) = 2xy
 $$
then the locus is  $$ 2xy = 4 $$
$$ xy = 2 $$

then it's the line  $$ xy = 2 $$

what does this equation describe?

Comment: A rectangular hyperbola

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get the equation $2xy=4$. This is a hyperbola, not a line. You are undoubtedly familiar with its close relative, $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$.

You can put the hyperbola $xy=2$ into more familiar form by letting $x=\frac{u+v}{\sqrt{2}}$, $y=\frac{u-v}{\sqrt{2}}$. This is just a rotation. Then $xy=2$ becomes $u^2-v^2=4$.

Comment: I had a big mistake...look at the question now

Comment: It is a hyperbola.

Comment: what is a rectangular hyperbola?

Comment: @MuhammadKhalifaTranCer: It is a hyperbola whose asymptotes are at right angles to each other. But I removed the term since it does not add to the answer.